# How to get Firefox' about:home page look like the one on Windows?

Tags: firefox

I'd like to have this as my homepage:

[image]

Do I have to replace some files or link to a page, could anyone please tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the ubufox extension and it will return to the default Firefox home page (namely that).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is exactly the same, but you can try this:  http://www.google.com/firefox/

To set this as your homepage you will go to Firefox's menu: Edit (or Firebox button) > Preferences > General > Home Page:

Copy the URL into the "Home Page:" line

Comment: this isn't the same page, it's the google home page.

Answer (score 0):

Look under Windows, what is set up as your home page, and enter the same url under Linux.

Edit: Settings: First tab: Homepage: ....

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what my about:home looks like on both my Ubuntu 11.04 and my Ubuntu 11.10 Beta 1 (in a few hours).